# React - Redux : async call with Thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm learning to use react-redux, in particular I would to retrieve information by making an API call.

I have structured at the moment my project in this way:

```
/src
  /Components
   MeetingInformation.js
  /Redux
   actions.js
   reducers.js
   store.js
 App.js
```

in my **action.js**

```
export const meetingInformation = (meeting) => {
    return(dispatch) => {
        fetch('apiLinkToTheMeeting')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(meeting => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'MEETING_INFORMATION',
                meeting: meeting
            })
        })
    }
}
```

**reducers.js**

```
const initialState = {
    meeting: []
}

export const meetingReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'MEETING_INFORMATION':
            return [...state, ...action.meeting]
    }
    return state;
}

export default meetingReducer;
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { meetingReducer } from './reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export const store = createStore(
    meetingReducer, 
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(
            thunk
        )
    )
);
```

**MeetingInformation.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { meetingInformation } from '../Redux/actions';

class MeetingInformation extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            meetingMotivation: '',
            start: ''
        }
    }
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.meetingInformation()
}
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.meetingInformation(this.state)
}

render(){
    console.log(this.props)
    return(
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}}
const mapDdispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        meetingInformation: (meeting) => dispatch(meetingInformation(meeting))
    }
}
export default connect(null, mapDdispatchToProps)(MeetingInformation)
```

Now I don't know if what I have done is right, but the console.log of MeetingInformation is empty and also I have an error in action:

Meeting information seem to be empty

```
{meetingInformation: ƒ}
meetingInformation: meeting => {…}
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 1
name: "meetingInformation"
__proto__: ƒ ()
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   actions.js:6
```

EDIT:

The log of the response is:

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "myapiurl", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
type: "basic"
url: "myapiurl"
redirected: false
status: 200
ok: true
statusText: "OK"
headers: Headers
__proto__: Headers
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
__proto__: Response
```

What I should to do is to recover information using thunk from my db. How can I do?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you log the response in `.then(res => res.json())` before calling the `json()` method? Maybe your getting HTML from your endpoint instead of json

Comment: @HaraldGliebe Ok i have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note.

- You are logging `this.props`. At this stage, your props has the method `meetingInformation`. You will need to map redux state to your props.

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        meeting: state,
    }
};
```

- In your reducer, you are spreading state i.e. `return [...state, action.meeting]`. Even if you current problem is solved you will still have issue with your reducer. So spread state.meeting i.e. `[...state.meeting, action.meeting]`
- The error you are getting depends on the data structure that your api returns.
  You have printed response but stuff in `body` is hidden. So print and analyse the body of response.

I have taken your code & tested it in local with an example API and it works.

See the working demo here. Analyse my code and make required changes to your code and see how it goes. Any further issues provide proper api response logs which will be helpful to debug.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-black-fh8rd?file=/src/components/MeetingInformation.js

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have fix what you said :) I think that the problem is about my api in codeigniter because now I receive the error when I do the api call: has been blocked by CORS. (your codesandbox said the store is undefined)

Comment: I have not understand this part: The error you are getting depends on the data structure that your api returns. You have printed response but stuff in body is hidden. So print and analyse the body of response.

Comment: i was talking about log you provided, do you see `body: (...)` ... Response is a huge object and we are interested in response body... anyway, cool, so take care of CORS then ...